# HTML2Canvas DOM (Angular)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html2canvas

I'm new to JS and development in general, but I was hoping I could get a little help resolving an issue I've been trying to figure out for a couple of days.

Basically, I'm trying to get HTML2Canvas to play with Angular.  I have a div (ID is 'invoice') inside one of my partial HTML files, and I have the following in my controller:

```
sampleApp.controller('InvoiceController', function($scope) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var source = document.getElementById('invoice');




        $( '.submit' ).click(function() {

          html2canvas(source, {
               logging: 'on',
              allowTaint: 'true',
             onrendered: function(canvas) {
                  var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                 window.open(myImage);
            }
         });



        });
});
```

I'm completely at a loss as to why this doesn't work.  The script runs without any errors, but it just kicks out a blank page without an image on it.  It looks like it's something with the DOM because this is what I'm getting in the console:

```
html2canvas: Preload starts: finding background-images html2canvas.js:21
html2canvas: Preload: Finding images html2canvas.js:21
html2canvas: Preload: Done. html2canvas.js:21
html2canvas: start: images: 0 / 0 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js:21
Finished loading images: # 0 (failed: 0) html2canvas.js:21
html2canvas: Renderer: Canvas renderer done - returning canvas obj
```

EDIT:  Thought I'd add that another reason I know it's something with how the DOM loads in Angular is because using document.body as the var works.  I'm just looking to make an image out of a single div, however.

Comment: Add `console.log(source);` as the first line in your click handler to make sure you actually have the source element.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply, Jon.  I tried that, and the 'source' div correctly appears in the console. Any ideas?

Comment: Double check the contents of source `console.log($(source).innerHTML());`. I don't know if you exepanded the previous source node in the console to check it's contents. This will do it explicitly.

Comment: Okay, so when I tried console.log(source); I was able to expand it in the console and its contents were all there even though HTML2Canvas did not generate an image of them.

When I replace console.log(source); with console.log($(source).innerHTML()); it throws an error:

"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: My bad... try `console.log($(source).html());` but it looks like you're capturing `source` fine from your description. Try capturing a simple block with very little CSS applied, someting like `<div id="test"><p>Hello</p><p>World</p></div>`

Comment: Sure - console.log($(source).html()); worked, but even after clearing out the 'invoice' div to just <p>Hello</p><p>World</p> I'm still having the same issue.  

Anything else I could try?

Comment: @jayg, did you manage to run html2canvas properly with angular? If so, will you share some code and my be answer your own question?

Comment: @Sray - did you ever figure out how to use with angular?  I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Following is the exact directive i am using in my project, and it works for svg as well thus rendering the charts too:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('camera', camera);

camera.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

/* @ngInject */
function camera($rootScope) {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A'
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        $rootScope.$on('capture', function (event, deferred) {
            event.stopPropagation();

            renderSvg(element);

            //method to render the SVG's using canvg
            function renderSvg(element) {
                // First render all SVGs to canvases
                var elements = element.find('svg').map(function () {
                    var svg = $(this);
                    var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>');
                    svg.replaceWith(canvas);

                    // Get the raw SVG string and curate it
                    var content = svg.wrap('<p></p>').parent().html();
                    content = content.replace(/xlink:title="hide\/show"/g, "");
                    content = encodeURIComponent(content);
                    svg.unwrap();

                    // Create an image from the svg
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + content;
                    image.onload = function () {
                        canvas[0].width = image.width;
                        canvas[0].height = image.height;

                        // Render the image to the canvas
                        var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
                        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
                    };
                    return {
                        svg: svg,
                        canvas: canvas
                    };
                });

                    // At this point the container has no SVG, it only has HTML and Canvases.
                    html2canvas(element[0], {
                        useCORS: true,
                        allowTaint: true,
                        onrendered: function (canvas) {
                            // Put the SVGs back in place
                            elements.each(function () {
                                this.canvas.replaceWith(this.svg);
                            });

                            var dataURL = null;

                            try {
                                dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 0.9);
                                deferred.resolve(dataURL);
                            }
                            catch (e) {
                                deferred.reject(e);
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
    }
}
})();
```

Reference the above directive and use the following code in your controller to invoke the functionality in the directive:

```
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $scope.$emit('capture', deferred);

            deferred.promise.then(function (screenshot) {
                //do something with screenshot (Base64Url for .png type)
            });
```